# The configuration file has been changed by another program

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am receiving the following error where the system believes the web.config file is being modified.  The actual file shows no changes to the web.config file modified date since the site was last published. The issue shows up when being redirected to another page, though the pages where the issue occurs will change and the error will exist for any user who accesses the site. The issue can be temporarily alleviated by re-publish the application, but in about 24 hours the issue will return. Any ideas why it thinks the file is changing even though it is not?

> Current User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>   SERVICE Target Site:
>   BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne
>   Error:
>   (System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException)
>   The configuration file has been
>   changed by another program.
>   (E:\PEC\web.config)
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[]
>   keys, SectionInput input, Boolean
>   isTrusted, FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord
>   sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
>   at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord
>   sectionRecord, Object parentResult,
>   Boolean getLkg, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Object& result,
>   Object& resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean
>   checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean
>   requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String
>   sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex
>   index)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Authorization()
>   at
>   System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.OnEnter(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Do you have antivirus running?

Comment: I get the same issue from time to time as well, anti-virus is running on our server. I also restart our application pool when it occurs which fixes the error. But what would cause it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

We found this problem was caused by two different applications in IIS being configured to point to the same directory - we had a www.mysite.com and preview.mysite.com; we'd set up preview by using `msdeploy` to clone the main site, and not realized that www.mysite.com/foo was a standalone IIS virtual application - so we ended up with www.mysite.com/foo and preview.mysite.com/foo both pointing to the same folder, and 'fighting' over which one of them owned the config file, etc.

Removing the second virtual app fixed the problem.

Comment: This make sense

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was having a web deployment project with web config replacement AND a link to the external config file in the web.config like:

It seems you can only have one or the other. I wrote a blog post on it:
http://blog.coultard.com/2012/02/fix-for-web-deployment-project.html

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on a site I'm developing in Visual Studio.

I managed to solve the error by deleting the site's entire folder (the physical path), accessing the site through the browser, restaring the site and finally publishing the site again from Visual Studio.